# Moses called a liar

Tags: church-history

Muhammad,via Surah al-Qasas 28:38 calls Moses one of the liars.Comment please

How true is it that The Roman Catholic church educated and trained someone to become or he became Prophet Muhammad...God's chosen one,God's adorable one whom God created better than Angel Gabriel and all other prophets.

Comment: are you asking how/if the Roman Catholic church educated and trained Muhammad?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks us to comment on the teachings of another religion.

Comment: I've read (but unfortunately don't remember where) that Muhammad's contacts with Christians (before he created Islam) were not with Roman Catholics but with Nestorians.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity Stack Exchange.  When you have a moment, please take the Christianity Stack tour to learn more about us:  https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour  This is how we are different to other sites: https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites/1809#1809  Please also edit the top line which is supposed to be a question - what, exactly are you asking?

Answer (score 2):

There is, indeed, a connection between Islamic teachings and Christian teachings, for both religions hold the prophet Moses in high esteem, and neither call Moses "a liar".

I checked my English translation of the Qur'an at the reference you gave and note that it was the pagan Pharaoh who called Moses a liar. Let me quote the verse in question, for clarity:

> Pharaoh said: 'O Chiefs! No god do I know for you but myself:
>   therefore, O Haman! Light me a [kiln to bake bricks] out of clay, and
>   build me a lofty palace, that I may mount up to the god of Moses: but
>   as far as I am concerned, I think [Moses] is a liar!'

So, it is quite clear from the Qur'an itself that it was the pagan Pharaoh who was calling Moses a liar, and that is evident from the way this Pharaoh refused 10 times to do what the God of Moses commanded, despite the plagues God sent, as promised. That accusation of Moses being a liar was uttered thousands of years before Jesus Christ, and Christianity, appeared on the world scene.

However, your second question is not related to this, and really should be asked separately (which is why some people may have objected to it.)

I will briefly address it, because I have just finished attending a series of lectures on Christian Church history, taken by a Christian scholar who was taught by Greek Orthodox Bishop of Pergamum, John Zizoulias. I made a note that the lecturer said this Bishop believed that the Catholic church taught that the religion of Islam was a corrupted copy of the Christian faith.  However, he did not go into any details, so when the lectures resume, I will ask him to clarify. It may well be, as Andreas Blass commented to you, that it was the Nestorians who stated this, and not the Christian faith in general. Granted that the Nestorians are about the most ancient source of Christianity still existing today, there seems to be merit in checking this out. However, your claim that "The Roman Catholic church educated and trained someone to become or he became Prophet Muhammad" just reeks of nonsense. After I have met up with my lecturer next month, I may be able to add more to this answer, assuming it is still open.  I hope it is, for despite the objections raised by some, there is a point here that is worthy of examination, if only to refute it.

And I repeat that there are a few valid areas of similarity between Islam and Christianity, so that it can sometimes be fitting for a question that links the two religions to be asked here, on Stack Christianity.

Comment: I reckon having read rapidly and decided too quick to react.Thanks for enlightening me.I apologize to concerned.It was really the pharaoh commenting about Moses.